# Rutherford scattering: question about impact parameter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, scattering

http://wonka.physics.ncsu.edu/~blondin/py203/HW5solns.pdf

I have a question about the solution to a problem I found online. I don't understand why the author plugs in $\theta=90$ when the question is asking about angles greater than 90.

> a) What fraction...at angles **greater than 90 degrees**

Was he/she right in doing it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says at the start of the solution

> the fraction of incident particles scattered through an angle greater
>   than $\theta$ is given by . . . .

So that formula is being applied.

It might well be that the formula was derived by first finding the fraction scattered from $0^\circ$ up to and including $\theta$ and then that fraction taken away from $1$ to give the graction for an angle greater than $\theta$?